# LzmaDecode Error when loading OpenWrt image on Compex WPJ558

Tags: openwrt

I have compiled my version image for Compex WPJ558, and I'm facing this strange error while Uncompressing Kernel Image.

This is what the error says

> ERROR: LzmaDecode.c, 543
>   Decoding error = 1
>   LZMA ERROR 1

Is there something wrong with my kernel configuration or is this the issue related to WPJ558's default u-boot?

Some links says that there are issues due to the command line arguments provided during the lzma compression. I have tried those but with no luck.

Comment: Did you try downloading an image from openwrt site? Or compile your firmware with default config (remove your config, issue `make menuconfig`, select your platform and compile)

Comment: I downloaded the SDK from the Compex Website. After that I selected the Compex WPJ558 board in the make menuconfig, and along with that I also enabled some other user space packages.
I would try out the default config build and then let you know in a while.
Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please also try pre-compiled image from this page: http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/compex/wpj558

Comment: Hi Vasily, The default image from the link that you provided is not working with an error Uncompressing Kernel Image ... ERROR: LzmaDecode.c, 543. Is this the issue related to u-boot? Or is it the issue with the image? I'm trying to load the image via TFTP method with this command - tftp 0x80060000 openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wpj558-16M-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin. Is there an issue in the way that I load the image?

Comment: Try `tftpboot 0x81000000 image.bin`; `erase 0x9f030000 +<size>`; `cp.b 0x81000000 0x9f030000 <size>`; `bootm 0x9f030000`.

Comment: Am I always supposed to flash the image? Can't I boot from the image that has been loaded from the RAM?

Comment: It depends on the bootloader. Generally, some values are hardcoded, so your firmware must be located at the pre-defined location in flash.

Comment: I'm using the default bootloader provided along with the board. So there is no way that I can load my intermediate build from RAM, and leaving the flash untouched?
 In other words is there a way of booting the image from RAM without flashing the image with the current bootloader? Currently the bootloader prompt says `ath>`